# Dot not matching text with newlines while trying to parse BBCode with regex

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing, bbcode

I am using a little BBCode parsing function for a forum I have.

It works well when the text between two b tags has no newlines in it.

```
[b]Text[/b]
```

it will print Text in bold.

However, if the inner text contains a newline, it doesn't replace properly.

```
[b]
Text[/b]
```

My function:

```
function BBCode ($string) {
    $search = array(
        '#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#',
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<b>\\1</b>',
    );
    return preg_replace($search , $replace, $string);
}
```

Then when echo'ing it:

```
echo nl2br(stripslashes(BBCode($arr_thread_row[main_content])));
```

Sample text:

```
[b]    

Text

[/b]
```

Should become:

```
<b>

Text

</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [multiline modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), which makes your pattern something like `#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#ms`

(note the trailing `m`)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to have an effect tho, but thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Alex: To use `.` and match new lines I believe you also need the `s` modifier. (updated post above)

Comment: The `m` modifier is absolutely useless on a pattern which has no meta anchors (`^` or `$`).

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a [pecl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) that parses BBcode, which would be faster and more secure than writing it from scratch yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I use this... It should work.

```
$bb1 = array(
"/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is",
"/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is",
"/\[img\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is",
"/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is",
"/\[red\](.*?)\[\/red\]/is",
"/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is",
"/\[h(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/h(.*?)\]/is",
"/\[php\](.*?)\[\/php\]/is"
);

$bb2 = array(
'<a href="\\1">\\1</a>',
'<img alt="" src="\\1"/>',
'<img alt="" class="\\1" src="\\2"/>',
'<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="\\1">\\2</a>',
'<span style="color:#ff0000;">\\1</span>',
'<span style="font-weight:bold;">\\1</span>',
'<h\\1>\\2</h\\3>',
'<pre><code class="php">\\1</code></pre>'
);

$html = preg_replace($bb1, $bb2, $html);
```